# HTML Event Handler when Required Digits is Typed

Tags: javascript, html

So I am trying to write some HTML code that will trigger the function `disableBtn()` when a minimum of 8 characters is written in the text field.
This is what I have so far:

```
Now of course oninput causes the function to be called as soon as anything is written.  
Any ways to get around this?
```

Comment: Quick and dirty: `oninput="if (this.value.length >= 8) disableBtn();"` (don't actually use this, assign an event handler function)

Comment: `oninput="this.value.length > 7 && disableBtn()"` would be the unrecommended way, fitting your code.

Comment: @ChrisG I tried your "quick and dirty" way just for experimentation and it didn't work, do you know why?

Comment: Right, you have to add it to the `<input>`, not the <div>.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you will want to change the function you call on input to do a check on the field, eg.

```
<input
  id="UserID"
  class="validate"
  type="email"
  minlength="8"
  required
  oninput="disableBtnWhenValid(this)"
>
```

Note I moved the `oninput` attribute to the input element itself, which allows it to pass a reference to itself to the function `disableBtnWhenValid`.

To implement the function, you have a few options. You can do a quick and dirty check on the length:

```
function disableBtnWhenValid (inputEl) {
  if (inputEl.value.length >= 8) {
    disableBtn()
  }
}
```

However, since you've already stated the `minlength` constraint on the input, it's not ideal to have to repeat it in your function, and risk the two going out of sync as the code changes. You can use the [ValidityState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ValidityState) API here: calling `inputEl.validity.tooShort` will return whether the input value satisfies your `minlength` constraint.

```
function disableBtnWhenValid (inputEl) {
  if (!inputEl.validity.tooShort) {
    disableBtn()
  }
}
```

You can instead check *all* of your validity constraints with `inputEl.checkValidity()`. In your case this would mean that `disableBtn` would only be called once the input has a value of length >= 8 *and* matches the pattern of an email, ie. contains an `@` between valid characters.

Note that `validity.tooShort` isn't compatible with IE.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

```js
UserID.addEventListener("input", function() {

  if (UserID.value.length == 8) {

    // disableBtn();

    console.log("8"); // Added here just to check if code works

  }

});
```

```html
<div class="input-field col s12">
  <input id="UserID" type="Email" class="validate" minlength="8" required>
  <label for="UserID">UserID</label>
</div>
```